# ExecuteScalar: "Connection not initialized"

Tags: c#, ado.net

I attempted this but it won't actually perform my `ExecuteScalar` statement - it throws an error: "ExecuteScalar connection has not been initialized".

```
bool valid = false;
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(cstr);
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("Select case when exists ((Select id, phone, address From sys.views where name = 'employeedatabase')) Then 1 else 0 end");
sqlconn.Open();
//Here is where the error hits
valid = (int)sqlcomm.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
```

Comment: Should use [SqlCommand(string cmdText,SqlConnection connection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx)

Comment: Make sure you are closing the `SqlConnection` too. Its best to wrap using(...) around the `sqlconn` and `sqlcomm` and then you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't assigned the connection to the command:

```
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("Select case when exists ((Select id, phone, address From sys.views where name = 'employeedatabase')) Then 1 else 0 end", sqlconn);
```

You can either use the constructor overload as shown above or the [`Connection` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("Select case when exists ((Select id, phone, address From sys.views where name = 'employeedatabase')) Then 1 else 0 end");
sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
```

**Side-note**: i would use the `using`-statement to ensure that the connection gets closed even on error:

```
using(SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(cstr))
using(SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("Select case when exists ((Select id, phone, address From sys.views where name = 'employeedatabase')) Then 1 else 0 end", sqlconn))
{
    sqlconn.Open();
    // ...
} // you don't need to close it yourself
```

Comment: I updated my code with your 2nd example listed, but this produces a SqlException was unhandled -- Invalid object name 'sys.views'

Comment: @user3535895: that's a different question which is not related to the connection/command issue. Ask another question since it's difficult to help via comments and you should always ask one issue in one question. Otherwise it's not helpful for future visitiors.

Comment: @user3535895: note that i've edited my answer to show how you use the `using`-statement on disposable objects to ensure that unmanaged resources(like a connection) are cleaned up. That'll also close the connection.